# CASE WHEN statement as a stored procedure or function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, case-when

I have a lot of CASE WHEN statements in my queries that I often use in other queries.

Is there a way to store these CASE WHEN statements so that I can recall them whenever needed?  Or, do these have to be written out every time?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a Link table to store values for each case and then join to that table and get values from there at run time.]

Comment: Depending on your RDBMS, you could put the logic into a function, and then call the function with whatever parameters your logic needs so it can spit out a result.

Comment: Another option might be a view that contains those conditions. Btw: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: I tried the view option...but that wasn't very useful.  I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code snippets and templates:

https://ctrlshiftb.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/snippets-for-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/

Comment: Thanks, this works great.  I tried all sort of things and couldn't find anything in searches.

Comment: Learned something new today.

Comment: What about in a procedure ? I;m basically doing the same thing without the RETURN and nothing works

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly encapsulate a `CASE-WHEN` in a function, then call it from your SQL. However, if you're doing this a lot, you may want to consider if it makes more sense to put these values in a lookup table and find the value by joining.

Below is a sample function, for Oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION case_alternative (value1 NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
   RETURN CASE value1
             WHEN 1 THEN 'First Value'
             WHEN 2 THEN 'Second Value'
             ELSE 'Other Value'
          END;
END case_alternative;
```